# iOS In App Purchases - how should i check if user has a subscription?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am offering a 1 year subscription in my app. Each time the user enters the app, i need to know that the user is subscribed. I know i can use the 'Restore' procedure but according to apple documentation i should not do that.

So what is the correct way to check if user is already subscribed?